# Is OnCreate() The Best Place To Set Text?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview, oncreate

I am passing data from Activity A to MessageDetailActivity. Is OnCreate() the right place to set the text?

```
public class MessageDetailActivity extends Activity {

        private TextView bodyTextView;
         /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setupUI();
        }

        public void setupUI(){
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

            this.bodyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bodyTextView);
            Log.d("VALUE IS", bundle.getString("message"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), bundle.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bodyTextView.setText(bundle.getString("message"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `MessageDetailActivity` is a singletop activity, oncreate will be called only once. so onResume would be a better place to set text.

Answer (score 0):

An activity is restarted whenever the view associated is no longer visible.  The onCreate is only called when the activity is first constructed, not when it is restarted.  Because of this, a better place to set text would be at least in the onStart() method.  Take a look at the activity lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

In short, Yes.

However, if you want to give the ability to someone (i.e. a sub activity) to modify the text then you may want to set the text in onStart();

On another note, its very unlikely that you really want your setupUI() method public.